# change the value of background position with jquery or javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I get a Css value with JQuery ,regarding the background position of specific element,`-66px -65px`

I want get the second value`("-65px")`and change that to `'170px'` with jquery ;
How to subString that and replace now value?

Comment: Add a new style to an element, or just replace that number in the string ?

Comment: you could split the string at " " (space character), access the index [1] of the split array and change it, then join the array with a " " space character again. `var thevalues = yourposition.split(" "); thevalues[1] = "170px"; $(element).css("background-position", thevalues.join(" "))`

Comment: just change the number

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QhS6c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by your case

```
// replace body selector with your element selector
var bgPos = $('body').css('backgroundPosition');
$('body').css('backgroundPosition', bgPos.replace('-65px', '170px'));
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can do something like this...

```
    $('#elementid').css('background-position-x', newValueX);
    $('#elementid').css('background-position-y', newValueY);
```

also you can get the values

```
    $('#elementid').css('background-position-x');
    $('#elementid').css('background-position-y');
```

Comment: Note that this is not cross browser nor is it part of the CSS specs.

Comment: the "background-position-x", "background-position-Y" not in w3c standard

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use 'background-position' css property. It would make your life a bit simpler.

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgjeN/2/)

```
var bg = $('#some_el').css('background-position');
var values = bg.split(" ");
var X = values[0].split("px")[0];
var Y = values[1].split('px')[0]);
```